# display function not displaying data

Tags: c++

I am making tree. It is not displaying.

I have a string length 4 say SHAM now each character S H A M has four pointers and putting NULL in it. But when I compile and run display() function not working.

```
struct node
{
    string info;
    struct node **next;
} *front, *rear;

void enqueue(string s)
{
    node *p, *temp;
    p=new node[sizeof(node)];

            stuff goes here... 
    }      
}

void display()
{
    int k = 0;
    node *t, *temp;
    t = front;
    if(front == NULL || rear == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\nQueue Empty!!!";
    }
    else
    {
        temp=t;
        while(t!= NULL)
        {
            if(t->next[k] != NULL)
            {
                temp=t->next[k]; 

                cout<<temp->info<<" ";
            }

            k++;

            if(k==n.length())
            {           
                k = 0;
                t = t->next[k];
                temp = t;
            }    
        }       
    }    
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int ch, len, x;
    string string1;
    rear = NULL;
    front = NULL;

    cout << "\n1. Insert\n2. Exit\n";
    cout << "\nEnter Your Choice: ";
    cin >> ch;

    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "\nEnter The String: ";
            cin >> n;
            len = n.length();
            enqueue(n);
            cout << " len " << len;

            for(int p=1;p<=len;p++)
                bnod+=pow(len,p);

            cl = 0;
            for (x = 0; x < len; x++)
            {
                string1=n.at(x);
                enqueue(string1);
                cl++;
            }
            display();

            cout << "\n########################\n";
            break;

        case 2:
            exit(0);
            break;

        default:
            cout << "\nWrong Choice!!! Try Again.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You still have some of the mistakes you had in your previous question. Fix those first. Also, "stuff goes here... " is kind of an important part of the program I guess. Where's that code?

Comment: Oh, and *read* the error and warning messages, they are probably very clear about what you have to do (like undeclared variables etc.).

Comment: i have already done that now working for length N. not for fix length

Comment: @Artemis It would help if you update your code. We don't have a way of guessing which of the numerous problems in your code you have already fixed.

Comment: learn C++ first and then come out on the forum....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you started in the wrong way: your node structure contains pointer to a pointer.

```
struct node
{
    string info;
    struct node **next;
};
```

that might be the reason the code does not make sense. You can use (and generally you do things this way) a simple pointer:

```
struct node
{
    string info;
    struct node *next;
};
```

This way everything look more manageable:

```
node a;
a.info = "abc"; //this is your info
a.next = NULL //
```

this is the connection to the next node in the tree

Using pointer to pointer to determine the next element in your data structure is pointless(as far as I can tell from your example), and you have to be careful about memory allocation.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong way to `new` a type:

```
p = new node[sizeof(node)]; // p = new node; is enough
```

You don't need that `[sizeof(node)]` part. On the other hand I can not see how you initializing `next`.

So, I **believe** this code doesn't work properly.

Comment: i correct this in my previous post it is working correctly

Comment: @Artemis well, then don't post code that is not the one causing your problems